# awk: csv split works, but ignores the last field in the row

Tags: shell, csv, awk, pattern-matching

I have a sample file that looks like:

Sample.csv

```
Data_1,0,289,292,293,300,306  
Data_2,0,294,3,306  
Data_3,0,294,305,306  
Data_4,0,294,305,306
```

And Im running awk on it:
scr.sh:

```
awk -F ',' -v tId="$1" '{for(i=3; i<NF; i++){if($i==tId) print}}' $2
```

By calling

```
./scr.sh 300 Sample.csv
```

That works fine and returns me exactly one row that matches.
UK_4_AB34,0,289,292,293,300,306

Original Problem statement: From the 3rd column onwards, if any of the column data matches the number given, then the line should get printed.

But if I call:

```
./scr.sh 306 Sample.csv
```

That returns me NOTHING!
I've double checked the lines in Sample.csv and confirmed that there are NO trailing spaces on any of the lines.
Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: awk fields are 1-based, so maybe i<=NF as your for condition?

Comment: @jas is exactly correct.

Comment: Yeah, I'd missed that. i<=NF worked just fine! Thanks jas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk will do what you're looking for:

```
awk -F ',' -v tId="$1" '$0 ~ "(^|,)" tId "(,|$)"' file
```

Alternatively this `egrep` will also do the job:

```
egrep '(^|,)306(,|$)' file
```

**UPDATE:** Based on your comments below you can use:

```
awk -v tId="$1" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {p=$0; $1=$2=""} $0 ~ "(^|,)" tId "(,|$)"{print p}' file
```

Comment: Right and it'll solve his current scripts problem that if the same value appeared in 2 fields he'd print the line twice.

Comment: This matches the second column too. I dont want that, it should match 3rd column onwards. If Sample.csv has a line "UK_4_AL2,3,294,305,564" Then it picks up this line. It should not.

Comment: ok check updated answer now, it will only search from field 3 onwards now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to your problem.
Lets say your argument is stored in a variable named var
ie `var=$1;`

Therefore run the following command to find the occurences in your file

```
grep -E "^${var},|,${var},|,${var}$" yourfilename
```